# Joining two tables on the basis of Two colums in dql(Doctrine)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

*I want to join table on the basis of two colums.

- I have a dql  join query like this-

  ```
  $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
  $from = 'Entities\User u';
  $qb->select('u.id User_Id, u.name User_Name, evtvst.event Event_id,evt.name   eventname, cty.name City,ctry.name Country')
  ->add('from', $from)
  ->join('Entities\EventVisitor','evtvst','with','u.id=evtvst.user')
  ->join('Entities\Event','evt','with','evt.id=evtvst.event')...........#
  ->join('Entities\Country','ctry','with','evt.country=ctry.id')
  ->join('Entities\City','cty','with','evt.city=cty.id')
  ->where('evtvst.user=?1')
  ->setParameter(1,$_GET["user"])
  ->setFirstResult($i)
  ->setMaxResults($max_result)
  ->distinct();
  $query = $qb->getQuery();
  $query->getSQl();
  $results = $query->getResult();
  ```

now i am add one more condition to the # marked colum like this-

->join('Entities\Event','evt','with','evt.id=evtvst.event', and 'evt.eventEdition=evtvst.edition')

But it is not working.
pls tell a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i find out a solution for this

You just have to change the alias of the table while applying join second time.
    I have done like this

```
    ->join('Entities\EventVisitor','evtvst','with','u.id=evtvst.user')
    ->join('Entities\Event','evt','with','evt.id=evtvst.event')
    ->join('Entities\Event','evt1','with','evt1.eventEdition=evtvst.edition')
    ->join('Entities\Country','ctry','with','evt.country=ctry.id')
    ->join('Entities\City','cty','with','evt.city=cty.id')
    ->where('evtvst.user=?1')
```

and its working fine.